# How to display turtle coordinates on the canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

With Python 3.6 and the Turtle module, I would like to know how to print the coordinates of the turtle on screen.

My questions are: **How do I print text on the screen, and how do I make that text the player's coordinates?**

Here is my code.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

play = Screen()

play.bgcolor("black")
play.screensize(250, 250)
play.title("Turtle Keys")

def position():
    coord = follow.coor()
    coord.color("white")
    coord.setposition(130, 100)

run = Turtle("triangle")
run.speed("fastest")
run.color("white")
run.penup()
run.setposition(250, 250)

print(position)
```

Thank you.

**Edit** I tried `write`, but it throws a name not defined error.

Comment: I would like the whole traceback why `write` didn't work. For example, what name is not defined? I know it's probably `NameError: ___ is not defined` but I would still like to know what wouldn't be defined.

Comment: My error says  `write(run.position(), False, center)
NameError: name 'write' is not defined`

Comment: Then use `run.write`. If you didn't know, it's kind of obvious that you didn't import the `write` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can write the turtle position on screen: the `write` method from the `turtle` module, must be called on a `Turtle` object.

```
import turtle

playground = turtle.Screen()       # use nouns for objects, play is a verb

playground.bgcolor("black")
playground.screensize(250, 250)
playground.title("Turtle Keys")

tom = turtle.Turtle()              # use nouns for objects, run is a verb

tom.color("white")
tom.setposition(130, 100)
tom.speed("fastest")
tom.color("white")

p = tom.pos()               # here you get the coordinates of the turtle
tom.write(str(p), True)     # and you print a string representation on screen
tom.penup()

print(p)                    # this prints to the console

playground.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I don't think you should input `move=False` as `True`. It seems to do nothing except for making an underline. Unless you rather intend to make an underline, I would recommend turning it off.

Answer (score 1):

The way I approach this type of problem is to dedicate a turtle to each fixed label on the screen.  That way you can permanentely locate a turtle at that position and simply do `undo()` to clear the old text followed by `write()` to write the new.

Here's a dynamic example where you can drag the turtle around the screen with your mouse and the current position will be written to the center of the screen:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ('Arial', 24, 'normal')

playground = Screen()
playground.setup(500, 500)
playground.bgcolor("black")

runner = Turtle("triangle")
runner.color("white")
runner.speed("fastest")
runner.penup()
runner.setposition(200, 200)

marker = Turtle(visible=False)  # our virtual magic marker
marker.penup()
marker.color("yellow")
marker.write(runner.position(), align='center', font=FONT)  # so we can undo it

def drag_handler(x, y):
    runner.ondrag(None)  # disable handler while in handler
    marker.undo()  # erase previous position
    marker.write((x, y), align='center', font=FONT)
    runner.setheading(runner.towards(x, y))  # head towards new location
    runner.setposition(x, y)
    runner.ondrag(drag_handler)

runner.ondrag(drag_handler)

playground.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the functions `xcor()` and `ycor()` to get coordinates.  Use the function `write()` to write on the screen.

See documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html